# SPFieldLookupValue in Linq Query

Tags: linq, sharepoint

I'm trying to the the value of a lookup field in SharePoint using Linq and a collection of `SPListItem` - something like this:

```
   int totalDepts = (from SPListItem itm in hourEntries select ((SPFieldLookupValue)itm["Level1"]).LookupValue).Distinct().Count();
```

But that doesn't seem to work (and it strikes me as missing some steps)

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: by experience, Linq to SharePOint is a bit dangerous and hard to customize. My advise would be to create pure CAML query, event if the syntax is a bit more complicated. Most of all, using CAML query, you will be sure that your query will be handled by Sharepoint, and not in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out to do it directly in the Linq query, so I ended up creating WorkHoursEntries object, and populating it with all my SPListItems

```
List<WorkHourEntry> workHourEntries = new List<WorkHourEntry>();
                foreach (SPListItem hourEntry in hourItems)
                {
                    //Collect entries that are in the current Fiscal Year reporting period
                    if (fiscalYearMonths.Contains(hourEntry["Reporting_x0020_Month"].ToString()))
                    {

                    WorkHourEntry curEntry = new WorkHourEntry();
                    string Level1 = (string)hourEntry["Level1"];
                    SPFieldLookupValue val = new SPFieldLookupValue(Level1);
                    curEntry.organization = val.LookupValue;
                    SPFieldCalculated cf = (SPFieldCalculated)hourEntry.Fields["WECSCHours"];
                    curEntry.WECSCHours = cf.GetFieldValueForEdit(hourEntry["WECSCHours"]);
                    workHourEntries.Add(curEntry);

                    }
                }
```

This allowed me to run Linq queries directly on the WorkHourEntry collection

```
var uniqueDeptNames = (from itm in workHourEntries select itm.organization).Distinct().ToArray();
```